# Python JIRA SOAPpy annoying redirect on findIssue

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, jira

I am trying to do WSDL SOAP connection to our JIRA server using SOAPpy (Python SOAP Library).

All seems to be fine except when I try finding specific issues. Through the web browser looking up the bug ID actually redirects to a bug (with a different ID), however it is the bug in question just moved to a different project.

Attempts to getIssue via the SOAPpy API results in an exception that the issue does not exist.

Any way around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's an existing bug on this I've seen. Use the JIRA issue id instead of the key to locate it, as a workaround.

Comment: what is the difference between the key and id? I think they might be the same for the issues I am working with (will have to double check).